# Adding data using Python from ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS REST Services directory to a ArcMap MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I want to update over 100 MXDs by adding 4/5 ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS REST Services directory layers. I am unsure whether this is possible using Python and can only find documentation on how to access ArcGIS Online layers via the ArcGIS API and Jupyter Notebooks. How can I add data from ArcGIS Online via Python to a MXD or even how to use ArcGIS Online layers within ArcPy?

Sample code I've tried so far:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

trailheads_id = '7ff2ea905ad343f98dfd09a723938784'

gis = GIS()

trailheads_item = gis.content.get(trailheads_id)
trailheads_item


import arcpy  
# Hook into the map document  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Path\To\MapDocument")  

# Hook into the data frame where you want to add the layer  
df  = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site's focused Q&A format. For questions about code, please [edit] to tell us what is/is not happening when you run the code and also list the text of any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually attempt to extract the URL from the item or use it to add a new layer to the ArcMap document.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to add a layer using Python/arcpy to **ArcMap** is using the [arcpy.mapping.AddLayer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addlayer.htm) function. This function works with [mapping layers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm).

No matter what you do in the ArcGIS for Python API, you'll never get back an *arcpy mapping layer object*.  Meaning: you cannot simply do a search using the Python API, and pass that reference through to arcpy.mapping.AddLayer. These pieces just aren't functionality compatible.

Now an arcpy.mapping.Layer object is either a true layer object, or a pointer to a layer file (`.lyr)`. I suspect your only chance at making this work is if you had a layer file already created that referenced a web service. Then, using a function to update the data source of said layer file with a new URL, you'd then add this layer to your map. **However**, I'm doubtful you can actually update the data source of a layer file with a new web service URL. The [doc doesn't show any samples](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm) that do this, nor hint at the possibility.

In short, you'd need to the following in your code (and even then, I'm skeptical it'll work):

- Get the web service URL out of the item you've found. This would be from your `trailheads_item`
- Create a layer file from a layer in your map that points to a webservice. This will be your template layer file (`.lyr`)
- Create a reference to this layer file as a layer object
- Try to update the datasource of this layer object with the URL you've previously extracted using the Python API
- Add this updated layer file/object to your MXD. Save. Open the next MXD and continue on...