# Adding query layer to MapView in Jupyter Notebook returns "RuntimeError: Cannot infer layer: will not be added to map"

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook, query-layer, runtimeerror, arcgis-notebook

I am working within a Jupyter notebook, trying to display a query layer (querying a SQL database) into a map view within the notebook. I receive a Runtime Error (described below) when I try to add this layer to the map view.

Using the following code (with specific names changed for privacy reasons) I can successfully create a map and add a layer from my organization's enterprise portal.

```
# Import Statements
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import arcpy

# Instantiate Connection to Portal
gis = GIS("portal_url", username="my_username")

# Get item from portal
portalItem = gis.content.get('itemID')

# Create map and add portal item to it
m = gis.map()
m.add_layer(portalItem.layers[0])
```

I can also successfully create my query layer using the following code, including testing that makeQueryLayer returned a feature class with geometry as expected. This same query was copied directly from a successful query layer being created in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1.

```
# Create query layer input variables
out_layer_name = "queryLayerOutput"
sql_Query="""SELECT OBJECTID
                    ,Field1
                    ,Field2
                    ,Shape.STEnvelope() as MBR
                FROM SQLDatabase.Table 
                WHERE Shape.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(""" + lat_long_string + """)', 4326).STEnvelope()) = 1""" # lat_long_string being the coordinates of my area of interest in proper 'E S, W N' format
oid_fields="OBJECTID"
shape_type="POLYGON"

# Creating the query layer
MBRQueryLayer = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(geodatabase, 
                                                out_Layername, 
                                                sql_Query, 
                                                "OBJECTID", 
                                                "POLYGON", 
                                                "4326", 
                                                spatial_reference=spatialReference)

desc = arcpy.Describe("queryLayerOutput")
print("Feature class type: " + desc.featureClass.featureType) #returns 'Simple'
print("Shape field name: " + desc.featureClass.shapeFieldName) #returns 'MBR'
print("Shape type: " + desc.featureClass.shapeType) #returns 'Polygon'
```

Where I encounter problems is when I go to add the query layer to the map.

```
m.add_layer("queryLayerOutput")
```

Which returns the following error, the key line of which is "RuntimeError: Cannot infer layer: will not be added to map":
[image: Python output error from m.add_layer("queryLayerOutput"): RuntimeError: Cannot infer layer: will not be added to map]

The [documentation for MapView.add_layer()](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.widgets.html?highlight=add_layer#arcgis.widgets.MapView.add_layer) implies that I should be able to add a FeatureLayer, which to my understanding is what makeQueryLayer() produced. **Does anyone understand why my layer is unable to be added?** My best guess would be that somehow my data is not in an acceptable format for add_layer() to use. Somehow not the "right kind" of FeatureLayer???

I am working in the ArcGIS Jupyter Notebook environment (ArcGIS 10.7.1) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the same problem/answer here: [Adding data using Python from ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS REST Services directory to a ArcMap MXD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346592/adding-data-using-python-from-arcgis-online-arcgis-rest-services-directory-to-a)  --just reversing the layers and the map technology.

You're trying to use an **arcpy *thing*** and put that into a **ArcGIS Python API *map***. Basically, the layer you're trying to add to your map is not something the Python API understands. Yes, they might be both considered a *Feature Layer* (in broad terms), but they aren't equivalent.

I'm not an expert with the Python API, but my feeling is the map will want a **web-based** feature layer. The Python API is first and foremost a mechanism to work with services. It does integrate with arcpy and desktop functions; just not in this case you're trying.